# deferred.defer shows PermanentTaskFailure: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

I'm trying to import all the data from a csv file and stored it to the datastore as csv file..

`__init__.py` file where `app` is defined.

```
@app.route("/import/<model>", methods=['POST'])
def import_csv(model):
    reader = UsersImporter(fil, user)
    reader.read()
```

`importers.py`

```
class UsersImporter(BaseImporter):
    def read(self):
        line = self.file.readline()
        self.checking_delimiter_on_first_line(line)
        self.file.seek(0)
        reader = csv.DictReader(self.file, delimiter=self.delimiter)
        try:
            for row in reader:
                deferred.defer(self.parse_line, row)
        except:
            print traceback.format_exc()
        self.insert_entities()
```

Above code produces the below traceback.

```
INFO     2016-12-26 08:00:09,745 deferred.py:303] X-Appengine-Current-Namespace:, X-Appengine-Taskexecutioncount:0, X-Appengine-Country:ZZ, X-Appengine-Taskname:task8, X-Appengine-Taskretrycount:0, X-Appengine-Queuename:default, X-Appengine-Tasketa:1482739209.69
ERROR    2016-12-26 08:00:09,749 deferred.py:319] Permanent failure attempting to execute task
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gemini/softwares/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/deferred/deferred.py", line 310, in post
    self.run_from_request()
  File "/home/gemini/softwares/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/deferred/deferred.py", line 305, in run_from_request
    run(self.request.body)
  File "/home/gemini/softwares/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/deferred/deferred.py", line 145, in run
    raise PermanentTaskFailure(e)
PermanentTaskFailure: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

You see, `row` is not an instance of `requestHandler` class. And also `self.parse_line` is a method defined in the `BaseImporter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works, after moving `parse_line` function outside of the class. ie, the function passed as first argument of `defferred.defer` func  wouldn't be a instance method.